# Let p and q be coprime. There exists $X_0>0$ such that if $X>X_0$ then $\exists p^aq^b$ in $(\frac{3}{4}X, X)$.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

I was reading [this](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-proceedings-of-the-cambridge-philosophical-society/article/abs/note-on-a-problem-of-erdos/5A7100A1415170910EE5EC44AA77B390) article and the author states the following lemma as trivial.

[image]

In the lemma, $a$ and $b$ are positive integers and $p$ and $q$ are coprime positive integers, both greater than 1 (actually, for this lemma, I think it's enough that they are not multiples, but let's go with coprime for simplicity).

Is there a simple way to prove it?

A friend and I came up with a proof by using that there exists $x$ and $y$ positive integers such that $\frac{3}{4}<\frac{q^x}{p^y}<1$. But, as the author said it is trivial, I guess there might be a nicer way of proving it. It would be nice to have a nice heuristic to this problem too. Any ideas?

Comment: We don’t really use “coprimes” as a word - prime can be a noun, but coprime is an adjective that describes a condition on two or more numbers, so we say $p$ and $q$ are coprime.

Comment: Trivial often is unfortunately used as “is obvious to me but not sure how to prove it”. You can quickly show this using that $log(q)/log(p)$ is irrational, so you can approximate any constant with $q^x/p^y$, so you can get approximations between two adjacent powers of $p$ of that form which give you all $X$ from then on. Not sure if there’s something simpler.

Comment: Are $a,b$ supposed to be positive?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Lemma:** If $\alpha>0$ is irrational and $\epsilon>0$ then for some $Y_0$ we have, for all $Y>Y_0,$ that there is a pair of non-negative integers $a,b$ such that $Y<a+b\alpha<Y+\epsilon.$

**Proof:** Later.

**Main answer:** Let $\alpha=\log_pq.$ Since $p,q$ coprime, $\alpha$ is irrational.

Let $\epsilon=\log_p(4/3).$ Then there is some $Y_0$ which satisfies the theorem. Now, if $X>\frac{4}3p^{Y_0},$ then $\log_p(3X/4)>Y_0,$ and we know there are $a,b$ such that $$\log_p(3X/4)<a+b\alpha <\log_p(3X/4)+\log_p(4/3)=\log_p(X).$$

But $a+b\alpha =\log_p(p^aq^b),$ so we are done.

---

**Sublemma:** If $\mu>0$ and $(a,b)$ is an interval with $a>0$ and $\mu<b-a,$ then there is a positive integer $m$ such that $m\mu\in(a,b).$

**Proof:** Left to reader. Hint: Let $m$ be the smallest integer such that $m\mu>a.$

---

**Proof of Lemma:** Let $\frac{P_n}{Q_n}$ be the convergents for the continued fraction for $\alpha.$ Then you have, for $n$ even:

$$0<P_n-Q_n\alpha<\frac{1}{Q_n}.$$ Choose $n$ even so that $\frac1{Q_n}<{\epsilon}$

Letting $\mu=P_n-Q_n\alpha,$ then the sublemma means, given $K>0,$ there is an $m$ so that $$m(P_n-Q_n\alpha)\in (K,K+\epsilon)$$

If $K+\epsilon\leq 1,$ then $m<\frac{1}{P_n-Q_n\alpha}.$

Let $Y_0=\frac{P_n}{P_n-Q_n\alpha}.$ Given $Y>Y_0,$ let $a_1$ be the smallest integer greater than $Y$. If $a_1<Y+\epsilon$ then we are done - we pick $a=a_1,b=0.$

Otherwise, let $K=a_1-Y-\epsilon.$ Find $m$ so that $$m(P_n-Q_n\alpha)\in(a_1-Y-\epsilon,a_1-Y).$$ Then:

$$a_1-m(P_n-Q_n\alpha)\in(Y,Y+\epsilon).$$

But that means we can set $a=a_1-mP_n$ and $b=mQ_n.$ We know $a>0$ since $K+\epsilon\leq 1,$ we know $$mP_n<\frac{P_n}{P_n-Q_n\alpha}=Y_0<Y<a_1$$

---

If you absolutely must have $b>0$ let $Y_0’=Y_0+\alpha.$ Then if $Y>Y_0’,$ $Y-\alpha>Y_0$ so there must be $a>0,b\ge 0$ such that $a+b\alpha\in(Y-\alpha,Y-\alpha+\epsilon)$ or $a+(b+1)\alpha\in(Y,Y+\epsilon).$

---

For example, if $p=2,q=3$, $0<8-5\log_23<\log_2(4/3),$ and we can take $Y_0=107.$ Then $X_0=2^{107}\approx 1.6\cdot 10^{32}.$ That gives you a sense of how big $X_0$ needs to be.